# windows phone 8 : c# system out of memory exception : loading lots of images from the web

Tags: c#, memory, windows-phone-8, storage, windows-phone

This is one of the first applications I'm developing on the Windows Phone environment so I'm basically learning as I go. I have an application with a pivot control and on each of the three pivot items there is a LongListSelector. As you scroll images from the web are loaded into the longlistselector and this is infinite scrolling (since it just loads more once it sees your at the bottom).
However, in testing, if I scroll madly so that loads of images are downloaded I get the following error:

```
'System.OutOfMemoryException' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll
```

Because I'm loading some of the same images each time, I have implemented PersistentImageCache (Kawagoe.Storage) to cache the images.

http://kawagoe.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Storage.PersistentImageCache

Do I somehow have to unload the images as the user scrolls down, and reload them as the user scrolls back up? 
Or clear the memory for every X images? (I have the HTC 8S, so this may not be an issue with phones with more memory).

Thanks very much.

Comment: This obviously isn't a solution but something that came across my mind, what are the resolution of the images are you are loading for the phone?  Are you using larger images than are necessary for the screen size?

Comment: are you using a compiled version of the library or the source code in your project?

Comment: @Caimen The original images are 400x300px and I'm resizing them down to 210x158px, so there is a bit of loss there.

Comment: @NeilTurner I'm just running (debug) straight onto the phone. Would compiling it completely make a difference?

Comment: yes, as the code is quite old and designed for WP7. Storage in WP8 is also handled a little differently. Also, It will be easier to debug if you use the source code.

Answer (score 0):

Since you r developing for wp8, do consider using grid layout for longlistselector as shown in this sample:

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/PhotoHub-Windows-Phone-8-fd7a1093

Afaik they do many advanced memory saving techniques like paging 3 pages of content, lazily loading contents on item realization method and bitmap caching.

I have no problems showing 100s of hubtiles (notorious memory chompers)

Bonus tip:
You can control the scrolling speed by setting a lower maximumflickvelocity, which gives you more time to do what you need to do.